# Grok parse data inside square brackets

Tags: logging, logstash, logstash-grok

What is the best way to parse this kind of log with grok?

```
2019-03-15 14:42:38,910 INFO  [SID:6cd1c3cc-7fb0-4a06-8d4d-e125382568ca] [CID:60c24e3e-c8f9-43e4-bedf-59e861bfabf9] [http-bio-8080-exec-3] [TariffRuleServiceImpl.java:569] no approach by ShouldAddApproachToFixedPrice checkbox : false
```

I would like to get this kind of result:

```
{
  "date": [
    "19-03-15"
  ],
  "time": [
    "14:42:38,910"
  ],
  "level": [
    "INFO"
  ],
 "SID": [
    "6cd1c3cc-7fb0-4a06-8d4d-e125382568ca"
  ],
 "CID": [
    "60c24e3e-c8f9-43e4-bedf-59e861bfabf9"
  ],
 "thread": [
    "http-bio-8080-exec-3"
  ],
 "class": [
    "TariffRuleServiceImpl.java:569"
  ],
 "message": [
    "no approach by ShouldAddApproachToFixedPrice checkbox : false"
  ]
}
```

But I am stuck here: `%{DATE:date} %{TIME:time} %{WORD:level} ...?` How to get data inside `[...]`? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main idea of your Grok pattern should be to skip the square brackets with a backslash as for example `\[`. Once you have skipped them you can use a regular pattern to match your elements. Something like this would work as you want:

```
%{DATE:date} %{TIME:time} %{WORD:level}  \[SID:%{DATA:SID}\] \[CID:%{DATA:CID}\] \[%{DATA:thread}] \[%{DATA:class}] %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

Also, realize that you have two spaces between the `level` and the `[SID` and this could be making your pattern not to match depending on your construction.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't realize the 2 spaces. Thanks again

Comment: I didn't know this notation `SID:%{DATA:SID}`, I always use `%{SYNTAX:SEMANTIC}`. Could you give me more informations about that? Thanks

Comment: It just matches the `SID` word in your log exactly. It is a basic matching character to character so you can avoid taking that part and getting only what matches `%{DATA:SID}`. IT can also be skipped with some regex that matches only what appears after the colon.